# SSMS Removes comments when Enable Parameterization for Always Encrypted checked

Tags: c#, sql-server, always-encrypted

When you have Both of these settings

1. In the Connection Properties of the Connect to Database Engine, go to Additional Connection Parameters and enter the following: Column Encryption Setting=Enabled
2. Right click on your query pane and to go Query Options => Advanced => select Enable Parameterization for Always Encrypted

Now try to alter a proc that has comments in it

Viola.  Comments are gone and all lines have been reformatted to put a SQL Command into a single line.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes i have ...  When I Enabled Parameterization for Always Encrypted checked
Comments Lose in sql Server

Comment: Put the question in your question body please. (without arabic words SO is an english site)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [forums discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3175c5d4-db72-463b-a859-953610136e78/ssms-removes-comments-when-enable-parameterization-for-always-encrypted-checked?forum=sqltools), this seems to be a bug and it happens to every one. Lets hope Microsoft provides a fix or provide suitable explanation for this behavior